# How to Use HSQLDB in CMD Prompt

Tags: command-line, hsqldb

Currently, I am using HSQLDB version 2.6.0. I can connect and execute queries using HSQLDB GUI (runManagerSwing).

I want to know, how to connect and execute queries via CMD prompt? (Like we do for SQL Server, MySQL, Etc). I have tried the steps given in the below link. it doesn't works.

FYR - https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamkb/how-to-access-embedded-hsql-database-via-command-line-847749291.html

It would be great if anyone gives the step by step process. Thanks!

Comment: You need a command line SQL client that supports HSQLDB

Comment: sorry, could you please give a detailed steps?

Answer (score 0):

The steps are still OK. Use the SqlTool.jar version 2.6.0 and replace the URL with the JDBC URL for your database. If you have a problem, post YOUR config together the steps you are taking.